# Read data from HTML input form and POST them to using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, esp32

I have an embedded project using an ESP32 hardware working as Server. I need to load a large data file in browser into an HTML input form, than read it using a Java Script function, separate it into smaller files and send them to the ESP32 using the POST method.

I have a solution which sends the entire file:

HTML:

```
<div class = "upload">
  <form method = "POST" action = "/doUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="data"/>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" title = "Upload Files">
  </form> 
</div>
```

ESP32:

```
AsyncWebServer server(80);
server.on("/doUpload", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {},[](AsyncWebServerRequest *request, const String filename, size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final)
                                  {
                                    handleUpload(request, filename, index, data, len, final);
                                  }
                                  );

void handleUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest *request, String filename, size_t index, uint8_t *myData, size_t len, bool final)
{
  ...read data...
  request->send(200, "text/plain", "Upload done.");
}
```

This works, but the upload is very slow and sends the data in ~1.5kB chunks. I want to use the Java Script to divide the file and POST them by parts. This way I also will be able to let the user know of the upload progress (Java Script can update some progress bar after each 200 response). I tried the following just to read the file using Java Script first:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="jquery331min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="/canvasjsmin.js"></script> -->

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Dyno Wagen</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--<div class = "upload">-->
    <div>
      <!--<form method = "POST" action = "/doUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">-->
      <form method = "POST" action = "loadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="data"/>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" title = "Upload Files">
      </form> 
    </div>
    
    <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    
    <script>
        function loadFile()
        {
            console.log("loadFile");
            var file = document.getElementByName('data');
            console.log("length: " + file.files.length);
            if(file.files.length)
            {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e)
                {
                    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = e.target.result;
                };
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

But I get the following message in Chrome:

```
1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. VM:143.161
```

I never worked with JS before and only a litytle with HTML. I need advice conserning the error message above, also advice on how to proceed with this project.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to show the file upload progress, you may need to use Axios library.
You can watch the below video for reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nC3ntJUQrAM

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried following the tutorial, but my Web server on ESP32 has no internet access, so adding the script reference 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js' is impossible. I tried to download the 'axios.min.js' and load it to the ESP32 flash alongside the html files, but the line <script src="axios.min.js"></script> gives me a 404 error. Any idea why? This approach works well with other scripts, i.e. 'jquery331min.js'. Sorry if this is a silly question, I am totally new to JS.